# Error 500 after creating Group or Subgroup

Tags: gitlab

I upgraded my Gitlab Server to 9.1 and now I am not able to create a new group or subgroup. I get:

```
500
Whoops, something went wrong on our end.
```

I have no idea what to do. I reconfigured gitlab correctly and get the following error while trying to open the gitlab-rake gitlab:check log:

```
/usr/bin/gitlab-rake error: could not load opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-rc
```

**EDIT:**

The same happens when trying to create a wiki page. But I am able to create nwe projects and also new issues.

This is the ouput of my production log after trying to create a wiki page:

```
Processing by Projects::WikisController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bsYwgns56mTHZ398iqfA3ulAhZyci3yWI5VTDJGaaQJiUgSNWxlJEf5znRwNnWSsuq0ApA5GRPoqxuafY2AVPw==", "wiki"=>{"title"=>"test", "format"=>"markdown", "content"=>"test", "message"=>"Create test"}, "namespace_id"=>"GTE.TA", "project_id"=>"a"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 83ms (ActiveRecord: 5.4ms)

Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200 (localhost:9200)):
  app/models/project_wiki.rb:203:in `update_elastic_index'
  app/models/project_wiki.rb:112:in `create_page'
  app/models/wiki_page.rb:232:in `save'
  app/models/wiki_page.rb:180:in `create'
  app/services/wiki_pages/create_service.rb:7:in `execute'
  lib/gitlab/metrics/instrumentation.rb:156:in `block in execute'
  lib/gitlab/metrics/method_call.rb:23:in `measure'
  lib/gitlab/metrics/instrumentation.rb:156:in `execute'
  app/controllers/projects/wikis_controller.rb:64:in `create'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:93:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:16:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:10:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/rails_queue_duration.rb:20:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:29:in `block in call'
  lib/gitlab/metrics/transaction.rb:49:in `run'
  lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/readonly_geo.rb:30:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/request_context.rb:18:in `call'
```

And this the output after trying to create a new subgroup:

```
Started POST "/groups" for 10.181.42.75 at 2017-04-28 07:57:16 +0200
Processing by GroupsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9AOIcDjDkFFVYtuFKLhn5u28e4f9A2icB18wtNastnf4l7x/GOMzJGx2OeWvgsOUvlH+v2/OUPAODIUnJFbKSg==", "group"=>{"path"=>"asdsad", "parent_id"=>"51", "name"=>"asdsad", "description"=>"asd", "visibility_level"=>"10", "create_chat_team"=>"true"}}
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 146ms (ActiveRecord: 7.7ms)

    OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed):
      lib/mattermost/session.rb:75:in `block in get'
      lib/mattermost/session.rb:153:in `handle_exceptions'
      lib/mattermost/session.rb:74:in `get'
      lib/mattermost/session.rb:108:in `oauth_uri'
      lib/mattermost/session.rb:88:in `create'
      lib/mattermost/session.rb:39:in `block in with_session'
      lib/mattermost/session.rb:137:in `with_lease'
      lib/mattermost/session.rb:38:in `with_session'
      lib/mattermost/client.rb:12:in `with_session'
      lib/mattermost/client.rb:34:in `session_post'
      lib/mattermost/team.rb:11:in `create'
      app/services/mattermost/create_team_service.rb:9:in `execute'
      lib/gitlab/metrics/instrumentation.rb:156:in `block in execute'
      lib/gitlab/metrics/method_call.rb:23:in `measure'
      lib/gitlab/metrics/instrumentation.rb:156:in `execute'
      app/services/groups/create_service.rb:30:in `execute'
      lib/gitlab/metrics/instrumentation.rb:156:in `block in execute'
      lib/gitlab/metrics/method_call.rb:23:in `measure'
      lib/gitlab/metrics/instrumentation.rb:156:in `execute'
      app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:32:in `create'
      lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:93:in `call'
      lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
      lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:16:in `call'
      lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:10:in `call'
      lib/gitlab/middleware/rails_queue_duration.rb:20:in `call'
      lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:29:in `block in call'
      lib/gitlab/metrics/transaction.rb:49:in `run'
      lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
      lib/gitlab/middleware/readonly_geo.rb:30:in `call'
      lib/gitlab/request_context.rb:18:in `call'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the mattermost configuration. It seems that the gitlab 8.x Mattermost config are not compatible with gitlab 9.x. After commenting out gitlab is working fine.